# Jquery toggle jumps

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle, togglebutton

Could someone tell me a solution for this issue? As you can see, the div "jumps" when using the Toggle function.
http://codepen.io/AndrewRed/pen/vErjob?editors=101

```
<p>Text above animation</p>
<input type="button" class="btn" Value="Animate"/>
<div id="animate">
   <p>Text to animate</p>
   <p>Text to animate 2</p>
</div>
<p>Text below animation</p>

 $("input").on('click', function(){
    $("#animate").toggle('slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the margins from the p tags:

```
p {
  margin: 0;
}
```